# CRON-APT error on host [/etc/cron-apt/config]

Tags: raspbian-buster

Raspberry Pi 4A, OS v10.6 32bit

I have unattended-upgrades installed and every day at around 4:30am I get an error by email. The subject is "CRON-APT error on hostname [/etc/cron-apt/config]" and the body is:

```
CRON-APT RUN [/etc/cron-apt/config]: Sun Oct  4 04:00:01 BST 2020
CRON-APT SLEEP: 2277, Sun Oct  4 04:37:58 BST 2020
CRON-APT ACTION: 3-download
CRON-APT LINE: /usr/bin/apt-get -o quiet=1 dist-upgrade -d -y -o APT::Get::Show-Upgraded=true
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  python3-pgzero
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
E: Packages were downgraded and -y was used without --allow-downgrades.
```

"/etc/cron-apt/config" only includes the default commented-out lines. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

From `man apt-get`:

> --allow-downgrades
> This is a dangerous option that will cause apt to continue without prompting if it is doing downgrades. It should not be used except in
> very special situations. Using it can potentially destroy your system! Configuration Item: APT::Get::allow-downgrades. Introduced in APT
> 1.1.

I don't use `cron-apt` <sup>(Note)</sup>, but I would guess that your best move is to deal with this exception for `python3-pgzero` **manually**. I think you should try to understand **why** `python3-pgzero` requires a downgrade.

I think once you clear this issue, you'll stop seeing the errors.

---

**Note:** I did a search for `cron-apt` expecting to find a link to its source code, or documentation. [I found none of that](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=cron-apt&ia=web), which aroused some suspicion in my [reptilian brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triune_brain). There was [this from Debian's package site](https://packages.debian.org/stable/cron-apt):

> Observe that this tool may be a security risk, so you should not set it to do more than necessary. Automatic upgrade of all packages is NOT recommended unless you are in full control of the package repository.

It also strikes me as odd that the *source code* for the `cron-apt` binary is apparently *closed*.

Comment: I installed unattended-upgrades to make sure my headless and unattended RPi gets security updates. Not sure how I got cron-apt if it's not part of unattended-upgrades. Not sure why python3-pgzero causes problems or how to investigate it. I will look around. Apparently, it's required by games and I don't even have any installed.

Comment: @K4vcD: It should be safe to delete it then... Does this thing automatically reboot your system after an upgrade?

Comment: It doesn't reboot. It stopped period running after I uninstalled PiVPN and it ran again when I re-installed PiVPN. The PiVPN installer offers to install unattended-upgrades which makes sense but I think cron-apt is not part of unattended-updates. Strange.

Comment: EDIT: That was meant to be 'cron-apt is not part of unattended-upgrades'.

Comment: If it doesn't reboot, I don't understand how the kernel gets upgraded. And since other updates will depend on a particular version of the kernel...??? Sounds like a problem to me.